# Google app engine, not deploying with push to deploy

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Can browse updated source, and pipline looks cororect.

However no error messages, and no deployment ?

> Deployment type    Java: Use Maven to build, test, and deploy

Everythign builds, deploys fine locally. It just looks the web hook for deployment is not being fired ?

Answer (score 1):

The same is happening for me.  I see the webhook sent the POST from github when I pushed, but nothing happens on the appengine side.

**Solution:**

If you use `mvn appengine:update`, it will deploy the updates.

This must be an issue at the Google end of things not working with the webhook trigger.

Also, push-to-deploy does work when I use the Google repository. The only change I made was switching to my github repository and adding the webhook.

Comment: yep me too, took me while to realize there was a problem and use mvn as the solution. No logs or anything. Surprisingly lame from the big G.